# What's the difference between these two python import methods?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.7.6. I have two scripts:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

try:
    parser = HTMLParser()
except:
    print('something went wrong')

print('end')
```

which prints:

```
end
```

and the second script:

```
import html

try:
    parser = html.parser.HTMLParser()
except:
    print('something went wrong')

print('end')
```

which prints:

```
something went wrong
end
```

Why does the first one work but the second one doesn't?

Comment: Instead of ignoring the exception, let it go uncaught so you can see what got raised.

Comment: An "empty" `except:` statement is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.8/Lib/html) for the `html` library, you can get a little sense of what's going on.

`import html` will import the `__init__.py` file in the package. it has no knowledge of anything else in that directory, just what's in the file.

`import html.parser` will load what's in the `parser.py` file, but knows nothing of what's in `__init__.py`. Since `HTMLParser()` is in `parser.py` you have to either import the module and then call the class, or import the class directly.

Either of these should work fine:

```
import html.parser
parser = html.parser.HTMLParser()

from html import parser
parser = parser.HTMLParser()
```